# C# Deserialize JSON which does not specify a root element

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I am having issues processing a JSON in the following format,which doesn't specify a root element.

```
{
  "name":"Test"
  "age":"15"
  "gender":"Male"

}
```

My class to represent looks like the following.

```
public class Person{

 public string name { get; set; }
 public string age { get; set; }
 public string gender { get; set; }

}
```

Any my web method which processes is like below.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public boolean deserializePerson(Person person)
{
   //implementation code
}
```

This web service method fails to deserialize the JSON,  as it expects a JSON in the following format with the root element(class name in this case) specified.

```
{
   Person:{
      "name":"Test"
      "age":"15"
      "gender":"Male"
     }
}
```

Is there any way to deserialize the JSON without needing to specify the root element Person?
Perhaps via annotations?

Thanks.

Comment: How would you pass the parameters with a flat json if, for example, your method were `DoSomething(Person person, Company company)`

Answer (score 0):

if you have this class on both side it it will work perfectly

```
public class Person
{

    public string name { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }

    public string getClassSerialized()
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(this);
    }

    public Person getClassDeserialized(string sSerializedClass)
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Person>(sSerializedClass);
    }
}
```

to get the class back you may get it like this :

```
var myPerson = new Person().getClassDeserialized(sSerializedClass);
```